# Laravel -5: How do I get my form inputs to validate (among other things..)?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a few problems.

1. I can't seem to display the saved data inside my form inputs.
2. I can't get my urls to validate unique.
3. My controller code looks very redundant.

Getting the urls to validate unique takes priority though.

Also I created the table for sharing social links with a user one to many relationship. I think thats correct.  If not, please correct me.

**update**  Just a thought...I think I'm probably complicating things by only have a single 'type' column.  It would be easier if I had a column for each type of link i.e facebook col, twitter col etc.  I just didn't want empty columns if user didn't provide info for some services
Heres my code:

**UPDATE** I gave up and just added individual columns for the different types of urls and changed to a one-to-one relationship.

**form**

```
{!! Form::model($user_links,['method' => 'PATCH', 'action'=> ['UserController@update_social']]) !!}
                <div class='row form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        {!! Form::label('facebook', 'Facebook Username') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-7'>
                        {!! Form::text('facebook', '',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        {!! Form::label('twitter', 'Twitter Username') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-7'>
                        {!! Form::text('twitter', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        {!! Form::label('reddit', 'Reddit Username') !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-7'>
                        {!! Form::text('reddit', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                        {!! Form::submit('Save Changes',['class'=>'btn btn-md btn-success']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**controllers**

```
    public function show_social(Request $request){
      $user_links= $request->user()->links;
      return view('user.edit.social_connect',compact('user_links'));
    }

    public function update_social(SocialRequest $request){
      $facebook= Input::get('facebook');
      $twitter= Input::get('twitter');
      $reddit= Input::get('reddit');
      $user = $request->user();

      $this->validate($request,['url'=>'unique']);

      if(Input::has('facebook')||Input::has('google')||Input::has('reddit')||Input::has('twitter'))
      {
        if($facebook != ""){
          $link = new SocialLinks();
          $link->type = 'facebook';
          $link->url='https//www.facebook.com/'.$facebook;
          $link->user_id=$user->id;
          $link->save(); 
        }
        if($twitter != ""){
          $link = new SocialLinks();
          $link->type = 'twitter';
          $link->url='https//www.twitter.com/'.$twitter;
          $link->user_id=$user->id;
          $link->save(); 
        }
        if($reddit != ""){
          $link = new SocialLinks();
          $link->type = 'reddit';
          $link->url='https//www.reddit.com/user'.$reddit;
          $link->user_id=$user->id;
          $link->save(); 
        }
        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Your profile has been updated');     
      }
        return Redirect::back();

    }
```

**my model file**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;

class SocialLinks extends Eloquent{

    protected $table= 'social_links';

    protected $fillable=[
        'type',
        'url'                                       
    ];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
?>
```

my request

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class SocialRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

            return [
                'url'=>'unique|user_id'      
                ];
            }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have highlighted a few key words, this is done with double asterisks.  Great first post.  For a faster response next time, please consider posting your actual results.  Phrases like "I cant see to display" mean that others have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are a few things wrong here. Your request file is being used incorrectly. You need a model for that, unless ofcourse you're just getting "request file" and "model" mixed up. For the purpose of this comment, I'm going to use Laravel's validation method from within the controller.

Something worth noting, your "url" is not present within the form. The validation looks for a "url" parameter inside of the request, but as you do not appear to be sending that within the form, it is quite redundant. Also, when you use the "unique" validator, you need to supply a database table for it to search and check against the supplied value, in this case; url.

I've added that in, but, really it's not doing anything because the url will always be empty until you supply it in your form, so the request will always pass.

```
public function show_social(Request $request)
{
  $user_links = $request->user()->links;
  return view('user.edit.social_connect', compact('user_links'));
}

public function update_social(Request $request)
{
  $facebook = $request->facebook;
  $twitter = $request->twitter;
  $reddit = $request->reddit;
  $user = $request->user();

  $this->validate($request, [
        'url' => 'unique:social_links,column',  
  ]);

  if($request->has('facebook') || $request->has('google') || $request->has('reddit') || $request->has('twitter'))
  {
    if($facebook != ""){
      $link = new SocialLinks();
      $link->type = 'facebook';
      $link->url = 'https//www.facebook.com/'.$facebook;
      $link->user_id = $user->id;
      $link->save(); 
    }
    if($twitter != ""){
      $link = new SocialLinks();
      $link->type = 'twitter';
      $link->url = 'https//www.twitter.com/'.$twitter;
      $link->user_id = $user->id;
      $link->save(); 
    }
    if($reddit != ""){
      $link = new SocialLinks();
      $link->type = 'reddit';
      $link->url = 'https//www.reddit.com/user'.$reddit;
      $link->user_id = $user->id;
      $link->save(); 
    }
    return Redirect::back()->with('message','Your profile has been updated');     
  }
    return Redirect::back();

}
```

As you can see, I removed the type hinting for your request because what you were actually doing (from what I can tell), was type hinting the model. Your "request file" which you supplied is a model and should be in the App/ directory, and referenced using a namespace.

If you are indeed using that file as a model, then your relationship looks okay, assuming of course you've got the right foreign column setup in your database, referencing the user table.

As for your model binding not working, have you tried dumping the $user_links variable, like so: dd($user_links); - to see if it actually contains anything? As you're using a request there, I cannot tell where you're getting the information.

Hopefully this helps, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: ahh I posted the wrong file.  My model and requests are in the right place actually.  sorry.  also I tried passing in url to my form but I have 3 types (facebook, twitter, and reddit').  url only successfully gets passed for the first form input ('facebook').  This is my var_dump `array(5) {
["_method"] "PATCH"
["_token"] "XHE64X1ubnitqROjUBYEAiZLC3Po0KBS9N5l2ffB"
["url"] "facebookUsrname"
["twitter"] "twitterUsrname"
["reddit"] ""
}`

Comment: I see. You don't need the request file, you're only validating 1 field, you may as well do it from within the controller, like I've done.  'url' => 'unique:social_links,column', < this is the code. The "social_links" part is the table name where you're comparing the "url" too. Then the "column" part is where you're specifying the column name you want to run your "unique" check against. You need to specify these. "Unique" alone will not work.

Comment: In my case, the column name was 'type'.  'Type' would have a value of  the form the user submitted to.  So if fb username was entered, then $user->links->type = 'fb'.  Anyway in the end I couldn't find, or get right, the way to validate my 'type' column.  I was trying 'url'=>'unique:social_links,type->get('facebook') and stuff like that @_@.  I just gave up and added individual columns for each url type.

Comment: It looks like the input for "facebook" from the form was just that, facebook. So it'd be: 'facebook' => 'unique:social_links,type' inside of that validator within the controller. The validator takes all of the fields from the request. In this case, it'd look for the field named "facebook", search the table social_links, check the type column and return true/false if it can't find whatever the value of "facebook" was.

Comment: ohhh i see.  That makes a lot of sense.  I feel like I have a better understanding of validator now.  I always thought validator had to validate against the column name, and the column names had to be passed into the forms as well.  Makes sooo much more sense now.  Feel like a derp lol. Thanks IllegalPigeon!